# string with very special characters causes problemes

Tags: javascript, special-characters

I have a string

and I want the get the second character from this string

```js
// with a normal string the result is
var normalString = "abc"
normalString[1] // -> b
```

```js
// but with this one the reslt is 
var weirdString = ""
weirdString[1] // -> � I get this "replacement charactere" instead of
```

Comment: How do you check the out of the string?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff I log it in the console -> console.log(weirdString[1])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) here to spread string into an array

```
const weirdStringArr = [...weirdString];
```

**2)** Access the UNICODE symbol using index

```
weirdStringArr[1]
```

```js
var weirdString = "";
const weirdStringArr = [...weirdString];
console.log(weirdStringArr[1]);
```

Comment: Anyway it's a dupe - interestingly the dupe is using the same gothic alphabet.

Comment: @SkwalDev - The above is sufficient for a lot of use cases, but if the character ("glyph" would be the more accurate word) uses *combining marks*, even the above won't be sufficient because the glyph is made up of multiple unicode code points. Your string doesn't have that problem, but just beware of the possibility.